# Counting how many times a combination of words appear in a given line using Perl

Tags: perl

Dear Stackoverflow and Perl comrades:

I have a little question about Perl:
I'm writing a log reader. The log format is like this

```
    2013-05-27T19:01:23 [INFO] item_id:1, state:start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:29 [INFO] item_id:2, state:pause at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, state:start at Reader.pm line 23
```

...

My goal is to count how many state:start a given item_id, for example, item_id:1, shows. In this case, it should be 2.

So far what I have thought about is a counter of words:

```
    sub count {
    my $count_start = 0;

    open (MYFILE, $file_location) or die "Wrong filename";
    while ($file_location = <MYFILE>){
            while ($file_location =~ /\bstart\b/ig){
                    $count_start++;
            }
    }
    close (MYFILE);
    return $count_start;
    }
```

But I have to count not how many times "start" appears but how many times "start" and "id" appear in the same line. I know I have to add some regular expression but cant figure out anything. Any ideas?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the order of the field is predictable:

```
my %counts;
while (<>) {
    ++$counts{$1} if /item_id:(\S+), state:start/;
}
```

Comment: awesome that seems to work one little question what does the (\S+) actually mean? sorry for the newbie question

Comment: got it, \S+ means 1 or more whitespace characters

Comment: `\S` is a special character that matches any non-whitespace character in Perl regular expressions. The parentheses around it create a backreference, meaning that whatever is matched by the expression within those parentheses is saved (in this case to the built-in variable $1, because this is the first backreference in the expression). This allows you to extract just the number, and not the whole matching string (which would include `item_id:` etc..).

Comment: @adriancdperu It actually matches *non-whitespace* characters.

Comment: Thanks. So (\S+) creates a back reference for the pattern \S+, which matches any non-whitespace characters after "item_id:"

Comment: Correct. It matches the item id (the number following `item_id:`), and the substring matched will be available in `$1`.

Comment: I dont know why when I run the script I obtain an error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at log_reader.pl line 37, <MYFILE> line 1. It should have found some matches...

Comment: That message doesn't come from the script I posted. I don't know what you changed, so I don't know what you broke.

Answer (score -1):

A nasty one-liner for you:

```
mogul@guldager:~/tmp$ perl -MData::Dumper  -ne '$h{$1}++ if /(\d+), state:start/;END{print Dumper \%h}'<input-data.txt 
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 2
        };
```

Comment: OMG thanks. What does the (\d+) reg expression mean i wonder?

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated example - the OP will have to peel back so many layers in order to understand how to achieve what he wants.